# Route/forward traffic between overlapping subnets Linux

Tags: linux, networking, routing, iptables, subnet

I have configured a network with the following topology:

```
Gateway (10.0.0.1)
      | tun0
      |
      |-----------------------| 10.0.0.0/16
      |                       |
      | tun0                  | tun0
Host A (10.0.1.1)         Host B (10.0.2.1)
      | wlan0                 | wlan0
      |                       |
      | 10.0.1.0/24           |----------------| 10.0.2.0/24
      |                       |                |
      | wlan0                 | wlan0          | wlan0
Client A (10.0.1.2)       Client B (10.0.2.2)  Client C (10.0.2.3)
```

At the moment, hosts A and B can ping the gateway and each other. Also. each client can ping the host directly connected to it as well as the other clients connected to that host. However, I would like each device to be able to ping all other devices on the network (e.g., Client A can ping Client B, Host A can ping Client C, et cetera).

I have attempted several methods of going about configuring each host to allow packet forwarding between clients, other hosts, and the gateway. The first method I have tried is using iptables on each host to forward traffic between the subnets. While I have had success using tutorials such as [this one on Adafruit](https://learn.adafruit.com/setting-up-a-raspberry-pi-as-a-wifi-access-point/install-software) to allow clients to ping the hosts and the gateway, these did not allow other hosts to ping the clients. I also tried solutions such as [this one](https://superuser.com/questions/1230318/routing-network-traffic-between-2-subnets-using-a-raspberry-pi) to route traffic between subnets, but they seem to not work with overlapping subnets. I also attempted to create a bridge interface on each host that bridged tun0 and wlan0, with no success.

I am open to changing the configuration of IP addresses on this network provided the ability for all devices to connect to all other devices is preserved.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The solution (which appears painfully obvious in hindsight) is to assign IP addresses as follows:

```
   Gateway 
      | tun0 (10.0.0.1)
      |
      |-----------------------| 10.0.0.0/24
      |                       |
      | tun0 (10.0.0.2)       | tun0 (10.0.0.3)
    Host A                 Host B 
      | wlan0 (10.0.2.1)      | wlan0 (10.0.3.1)
      |                       |
      | 10.0.2.0/24           |-------------------| 10.0.3.0/24
      |                       |                   |
      | wlan0 (10.0.2.2)      | wlan0 (10.0.3.2)  | wlan0 (10.0.3.3)
  Client A                Client B            Client C
```

This puts the gateway/host connections on a separate subnet. In this configuration, the tutorials involving routing traffic between two subnets will work. Routes will need to be configured on each host and on the gateway (e.g., `ip route add 10.0.3.0/24 via 10.0.3.1`).

Comment: Maybe one should add that overlapping subnets are *always* an indication that something is severely wrong with the network topology. Avoid, avoid, avoid.